# Convert a Datatable to an Array of Doubles

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a DataTable object as the result of an SQL read. A typical example contains 100 rows and 16 columns. I need to iterate over the table multiple times extracting values for calculations (application is machine-learning gradient descent).
I am trying to speed up the calculations, and avoid having to cast the values read from the DataTable each time they are used. Is there a way to create a new 2D indexed array by casting the entire DataTable object just once, and therefore remove the need to call Convert.ToDouble 1000x100x16=1,600,000 times. Ideally for code readability I'd want to preserve referencing the data as ["colname",row]

Present implementation:

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    calculation = Convert.ToDouble(row["col1"])....
```

Comment: Are you able in storing them as double in the database?

Comment: Create a class to represent your data, then loop one time over the 100 rows creating the 100 instances of the class and add them to a list.

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert anything? If the values are loaded as double, you just need a cast - maybe not even that. Strongly-typed datarows expose values using their actual types.

Comment: If you want to speed things up the using ExecuteDataReader will likely be much better than dealing with datasets. Datasets are horrible for memory usage, and will be slower than ExecuteDataReader .

Comment: Or even better get your data as Iqueryable<customObject> with something like LinQ, or linQ on your dataset.

Comment: Gilad: Yes, data is stored as a Double in the database, but everything gets converted to an object when put into a DataTable object.  Steve:  Yes, I could loop over the rows, just normally someone here knows something more concise. Panagiotis: yes the cast seems to work (doh!) AndyJ: I don't fetch the table each time, so wasn't aware I could iterate with the same DataReader, is there a pointer reset? Pierre I'll take a look at Linq

Comment: @gregm the DataReader is a live connection to the DB, you should read out of it then close it asap so the connection can be used by others hitting the server. If you want to keep the data around then store it in memory and use that. You might say "but that's what the datatable does", and you're right ... but it does it in a very inefficient way.

Comment: @AndyJ: yes, I'm reading it out into a DataTable and the closing both the reader and connection.    
            dt.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            cnn.Close();

Comment: Changing from Convert.ToDouble to (double) takes 10% off the execution time, moving on to trying Zoran's approach below, then Sergey's

Comment: I don't need the precision of a double, so also might try float - and will have a search to see what the relative execution times of double vs. float arithmetic is

Comment: Sergey an Zoran should have negligable difference. But for future use, Sergey have strong argument, as he use a "named" object(DtoClass). this mean that tomorrow when passing a row to a function you dont send Something<object> with no type, no idea of the number of row, just Something. You send a <Dto>(find a better name) With know properties / default value/ decent constructor/ bringing is own logic.

Comment: Final Numbers in:  Convert.ToDouble on DataTable object=4.7secs, simple casts (double) on DataTable object 4.2secs, Zoran/Sergey approach 0.55secs.  As I started at 66secs, and now am at 0.55secs I'm pretty chuffed - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;    
DataTable db = <some table>;
double[][] arrayOfDoubles = db.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new [] { Convert.ToDouble(x["SomeColumn"]), Convert.ToDouble(x["SomeColumn"]), ... }).ToArray();
```

Don't forget to check for DbNull

Comment: ... and now you're having `EnumerableRowCollection<double>` which is not what OP asked for (two-dimensional array)...

Comment: @Nino Thanks for the spot, I have modified it now.

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom object to hold cell values of each row:

```
public class Dto // you can chose better name for dto class
{
   public double Column1 { get; set; }
   // other properties go here
}
```

Next convert your data table into dictionary of such objects, with row index as key:

```
var map = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select((r,i) => new { 
                RowIndex = i,
                Value = new Dto { 
                    Column1 = r.Field<double>("col1") 
                    // parse other columns here
                }                    
             }))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.RowIndex, x => x.Value);
```

After that you will be able to reference column value as

```
map[rowIndex].Column1
```

Answer (score 1):

`dt.Rows.Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r["col1"])).ToArray()` will return an 
 array of `double` and will have the same order as the original `DataTable`. You don't need to store a reference to the source row, since the index you're inspecting istelf will be the index of the original row.

Note that you'll need to import `System.Linq` and add reference to `System.Data.DatasetExtensions` for this method to work.

Do this once outside the loop and then run your loop on the resulting array:

```
var arr = dt.Rows.Select(r => Convert.ToDouble(r["col1"])).ToArray();

for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    for(j=0;j<arr.Length;j++)
    {
        calculation = arr[j] /* your operation here */;
        //dt.Rows[j] is also available if needed at any time
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to hold your figures, and maybe even put their some calculations as well.

```
List<MyCalculationOject> calculationOjects = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(
    row => new MyCalculationOject {
        Figure1 = row.Field<double>("figure1_Col"), 
        Figure2 = row.Field<double>("figure2_Col"), 
        ....})).ToList();

public class MyCalculationOject
{
    public double Figure1 {get;set;}
    ...

    public double SomeBasicCalculation() {..}
}
```